# Помогите разобраться с Redmine. Не запускается веб-сервер

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine

Не могу понять что требуется исправить...

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.16 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/application/configuration.rb:115:in 'read': No such file or directory - /etc/redmine/default/database.yml (Errno::ENOENT)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/application/configuration.rb:115:in 'database_configuration'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_record/railtie.rb:84:in 'block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in 'instance_eval'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in 'execute_hook'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in 'block in run_load_hooks'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in 'each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in 'run_load_hooks'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_record/base.rb:720:in '<top (required)>'
    from /usr/share/redmine/lib/plugins/acts_as_activity_provider/init.rb:2:in 'block in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/share/redmine/config/initializers/00-core_plugins.rb:12:in 'eval'
    from /usr/share/redmine/config/initializers/00-core_plugins.rb:12:in 'block in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/share/redmine/config/initializers/00-core_plugins.rb:2:in 'each'
    from /usr/share/redmine/config/initializers/00-core_plugins.rb:2:in '<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in 'load'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in 'block in load'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in 'load_dependency'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in 'load'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/engine.rb:593:in 'block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/engine.rb:592:in 'each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/engine.rb:592:in 'block in <class:Engine>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/initializable.rb:30:in 'instance_exec'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/initializable.rb:30:in 'run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/initializable.rb:55:in 'block in run_initializers'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/initializable.rb:54:in 'each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/initializable.rb:54:in 'run_initializers'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/application.rb:136:in 'initialize!'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in 'method_missing'
    from /usr/share/redmine/config/environment.rb:14:in '<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in 'require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in 'require'
    from /usr/share/redmine/config.ru:3:in 'block in <main>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/builder.rb:51:in 'instance_eval'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/builder.rb:51:in 'initialize'
    from /usr/share/redmine/config.ru:in 'new'
    from /usr/share/redmine/config.ru:in '<main>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/builder.rb:40:in 'eval'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/builder.rb:40:in 'parse_file'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/server.rb:200:in 'app'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in 'app'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/server.rb:304:in 'wrapped_app'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/server.rb:254:in 'start'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in 'start'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/commands.rb:55:in 'block in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/commands.rb:50:in 'tap'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/commands.rb:50:in '<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in 'require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in 'require'
    from script/rails:6:in '<main>'
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

```
No such file or directory - /etc/redmine/default/database.yml
```

Нет файла конфига для баз данных.

Стоит ознакомиться с [руководством по установке редмайна](https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RusRedmineInstall).
Там всё расписано.

Answer (score 1):

Обратите внимание на самую первую строчку:

> No such file or directory - /etc/redmine/default/database.yml

У вас отсутствует указанный файл. Исправьте эту ошибку и можно будет разбираться дальше.

Обратите внимание на шаг 3 из [инструкции по установке](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall#Installation)

Вот пример конфига для MySQL с использованием ruby 1.8 или jruby:

```
production:
  adapter: mysql
  database: redmine
  host: localhost
  username: redmine
  password: my_password
```

Comment: хайвмайнд однако (-:

Comment: Согласен, забавно вышло :)

Answer (score 0):

Вот отличная инструкция по настройке Rails https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.11-el-capitan

Скорее всего проблема не в RuByMinu а в не правильной установке Rails на ваш ПК.